# AJAX function hanging while trying to file_put_contents a base64 decoded file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email

I have a custom WordPress plugin that, among other things, needs to save a PDF file to the `uploads` directory and then attach that file to an email, all inside an AJAX function. I know there are better methods that could handle PDF creation on the server side, but the budget for this is tight, so I'd like to find a solution using what we already have in place.

Because this functionality was not scoped at the beginning of the project, we're somewhat locked in on using the existing HTML to PDF JS library ([jsPDF](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/jsPDF.html)) to create this file. We're using jsPDF for users who want to download the file locally, but now we need to try to email it to users as well.

On a local environment, the following code works fine, although it is slow. However, when I pushed it to the testing server, the process just hangs and never completes. It doesn't even return errors. It just simply keeps trying forever until it times out. I contacted the server support team and they could not find any obvious errors on their end.

The basic idea is that we take the output from jdPDF and return it as a string like so `doc.output('datauristring').split('base64,')[1]`, then in the PHP function, decode the string and save it as a PDF file. This is where the server seems to be getting stuck. No errors are returned and no logs seem to indicate anything, but it just gets stuck here, never even reaching the point of trying to email the file.

```
public function calculator_send_email() {
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'calc-nonce' ) ) {
        wp_die( 'AJAX nonce was not accepted' );
    }

    $to = $_POST['email'];
    // decode the PDF content and save it as a .pdf file
    $attachment = base64_decode($_POST['attachment']);
    $file = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/milkpay-' . time() . '.pdf';
    file_put_contents( $file, $attachment );

    $mail = wp_mail($to, 'Milkpay Results', 'Here are your requested results', [$file]);

    if ( $file && $mail ) {
        @unlink( $file );
    }

    echo $mail;

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code to find out which bit is causing the delay? Maybe remove some bit and see? e.g. maybe the saving is an issue (but not very likely), or maybe it's the email sending (probably more likely, and there might be extra logs relating to that you can examine).

Comment: I have, but I haven't found any issue yet. And on local, it runs fine, even if the base64 decoding and file saving is a little slow. On the actual server, it doesn't even seem to get to the email portion, it just stalls somewhere in the decoding/saving.

Comment: `somewhere`...narrow it down more. add some logging in between in each line so you can see. Or put `echo "finished"; die();` at progressively later points in the script so you can see exactly where the slowdown occurs.

Comment: e.g. does it execute `$to = $_POST['email'];` successfully and you can see the `$to` value? Does it execute `$attachment = base64_decode($_POST['attachment']);` and you can see the `$attachment` value? etc etc, until you find the exact line which starts to cause the delay. Also, check and make sure that PHP error and warning logging is fully switched on and then keep checking the PHP error log file on the server while running the code.

Comment: @ADyson it looks like you're right, it is hanging on the `wp_mail` step, although I can't get any data on why. I think instead of trying to do all of this in AJAX at once, I'll have it create a cron to schedule the email.